# Torch7 with CUDA (CUnn and CUtorch) - Torch Demos with MNIST

Tags: lua, torch, mnist

I have downloaded the demos of torch from github (https://github.com/torch/demos/tree/master/train-a-digit-classifier). The code works great in a CPU mode but I wanted to use it in a GPU mode with CUDA 6.5. I have installed all the prerequisites with CUnn and CUtorch and based on the documentation and tutorials I found, I added some lines of code to make it work:

In the begining:

```
require 'cunn'
require 'cutorch'
```

And in the end after the declaration of the model:

```
model:cuda()
```

But when I run the code, I get the following errors:

```
qlua: /home/ubuntu/Torch7/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Container.lua:67: 
In 1 module of nn.Sequential:
/home/ubuntu/Torch7/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/THNN.lua:109: bad argument #3 to 'v' (cannot convert 'struct THCudaTensor *' to 'struct THFloatTensor *')
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'v'
    /home/ubuntu/Torch7/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/THNN.lua:109: in function 'SpatialConvolutionMM_updateOutput'
    ...Torch7/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/SpatialConvolutionMM.lua:79: in function <...Torch7/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/SpatialConvolutionMM.lua:69>
    [C]: in function 'xpcall'
    /home/ubuntu/Torch7/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Container.lua:63: in function 'rethrowErrors'
    /home/ubuntu/Torch7/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Sequential.lua:44: in function 'forward'
    train-on-mnist.lua:227: in function 'opfunc'
    /home/ubuntu/Torch7/install/share/lua/5.1/optim/sgd.lua:44: in function 'sgd'
    train-on-mnist.lua:280: in function 'train'
    train-on-mnist.lua:383: in main chunk

WARNING: If you see a stack trace below, it doesn't point to the place where this error occured. Please use only the one above.
stack traceback:
    [C]: at 0xb6ae7bdd
    [C]: in function 'error'
    /home/ubuntu/Torch7/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Container.lua:67: in function 'rethrowErrors'
    /home/ubuntu/Torch7/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Sequential.lua:44: in function 'forward'
    train-on-mnist.lua:227: in function 'opfunc'
    /home/ubuntu/Torch7/install/share/lua/5.1/optim/sgd.lua:44: in function 'sgd'
    train-on-mnist.lua:280: in function 'train'
    train-on-mnist.lua:383: in main chunk
```

**Edit:**
The solution was to convert the data, labels and criterion into Cuda by using the `:cuda()` and the the script run perfectly. Thank you @lejlot

Comment: have you converted data to Cuda too? It looks like you try to pass a FloatTensor through :foward() on the :cuda() converted network, thus the type error. Try to call :cuda() on the input data too, before passing to the network.

Comment: Thank you very much @lejlot, you are right. I converted my data and also the labels into Cuda by `:cuda()`. There is another one that must be converted to Cuda which is the criterion with the same way. 

Thank you for your precious help.

Comment: Thanks! I was having the same error, I just forgot to convert my criterion.